# Proof dependence of two events

Tags: probability

Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$.
$X$ ~ $Bin(10, 1/2)$ and $Y|X$ ~ $bin(X, 1/2)$. 
Question: Proof that the events $X=5$ and $Y=5$ are depentent.

If $P[Y|X]$ were depentent, then $P[Y|X]=P[Y]=\dbinom{X}{k}*(1/2)^k*(1/2)^{X-k}$, which is clearly dependent on random variable X, Q.E.D.. But I don't think that is the proof they are asking for, so I had another idea.

$P[Y|X]=f_{x,y}(x,y)/f_x(x)=\dbinom{X}{k}*(1/2)^k*(1/2)^{X-k}$. 
Since $f_x(x)=\dbinom{10}{k}*(1/2)^k*(1/2)^{10-k}$, it should be possible to determine $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ and sum out the X variable. However, this is where I am stuck. Could anyone help me to determine the distribution of $Y$ or does anyone have a better idea to proof the dependence?

Answer (score 1):

They are not independent.

The distribution of Y can be considered as tossing $10$ coins and keeping the ones that turn up heads and then tossing those again and counting how many are heads a second time.  So $Y \sim Bin(10, \frac14)$  and you can work out $P(Y=5)$ as well as $P(X=5)$ and then show that their product is not the same as $P(X=5, Y=5)=P(X=5)P(Y=5\mid X=5)$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Law of Total Probability:

$$\begin{align}
P(Y=5) & = \sum_{x=0}^{10} P(Y=5\mid X=5)P(X=x)
\\ & = \sum_{x=5}^{10}\binom{x}{5} 2^{-x}\binom{10}{x}2^{-10}
\\ & = \sum_{x=5}^{10} \binom{10}{5,10-x,x-5} 2^{-x-10}
\\ & = \binom{10}{5,5,0} 2^{-15}+\binom{10}{5,4,1} 2^{-16}+\cdots+\binom{10}{5,0,5} 2^{-20}
\\ & = \underline{\boxed{\qquad ?}}
\\[2ex]
P(Y=5\mid X=5) & = \binom{5}{5}2^{-5}
\\ & = 1/32
\\ & = 0.03125
\end{align}$$

Are they independent?

Comment: The value in the rectangle is $\displaystyle{10 \choose 5}\dfrac{3^5}{4^{10}}\approx 0.0584$